# Visual Studio 2017 pop-up windows have transparent text when using dark theme

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Or, rather, the text is so low contrast that it appears transparent. I'm attempting to use ASP.Net MVC, and every time I try to add a controller, model, etc. the text in the dialogue that opens is completely unreadable. I've explored the settings a bit, but could not find a way to fix this.

[image: dialogue pop-up with low contrast text]

Could anyone point me to the solution to this issue? I attempted to google this, but was unable to find any answers. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Since posting this, reinstalling and changing each option under the "Fonts and Colors" to defaults/high contrast did not make a difference, and specifically I could not find an option where this window would change no matter what I picked.

Upon switching to the "Light" theme, the issue was somewhat resolved in that the text was visible, but this theme burns my retinas and I stare at VS for a good 10-12 hours a day. A solution that allows me to use the dark theme would be much appreciated!

It appears that the text inside the window is determined by the theme, but the color of the window itself is determined by Windows.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the color scheme?

Comment: I just did this on every option under the "Fonts and Colors" portion of the options menu, still no luck. Not entirely sure which one this would be classified under, but I did it for each listed item in a row.

Comment: I also just tried re-installing VS2017 with no luck.

Comment: I think you should go back to the Dark Theme, then down every item in the `Fonts & Colors > Show settings for` dropdown and hit `Use Defaults` for each one, then hit `OK`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then the colors may be coming from the Windows theme.

Comment: It didn't work. What seems to be the case is that the Windows Theme is determining the window color, but the window *text* is determined by the VS theme; since the Dark theme makes everything light colored, text is unreadable.

Comment: Then either modify the text color in VS (which is a pain) or change your Windows theme...

Comment: Although it's not the answer I like, it's probably the answer nonetheless. It seems like a lot of work for something my office colleagues also use as the standard theme without problem, however, with standardized machines.

Comment: Agreed. They have always struggled with the dark theme and I happen to like it a lot. I am also the only one in the office using it, lol. I like the fact that I can customize the colors but it's so granular that it's really complicated and too time consuming.